# Visual Studio Community 2013 will not let me install

Tags: visual-studio

For some reason Visual Studio Community 2013 will not let me install it on my computer. I've tried to download Community, Community with update 1, Community with update 2, etc. but nothing seems to let me install it. It will either tell me that it "Does not apply" or that my windows version (Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit) isn't recent enough, even though the requirements clearly state that Windows 7 is able to be used with this program. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[The log](http://pastebin.com/cU1cZLQe)

Thanks, Nick.

Edit: For clarification, this is the error that pops up when I try to run Visual Studio Community 2013 w/ Update 4 as an administrator.

[The Error](http://s28.postimg.org/5oa7zqtp9/Capture.png)

Edit-Edit: Christ, I have no SP1 installed... That's probably the reason.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? The 1112-line log file doesn't exactly make that clear. Under what circumstances does it give which error? You've tried multiple versions.

Comment: Oh, and just in case -- you *do* have SP1 installed like the requirements say, right?